# Как сверстать на css grid такую форму?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Как сверстать такую форму на css grid и чтобы она была адаптивной?
Нужно чтобы при уменьшении экрана input'ы расстягивались на 100%.
Проблема в том, что при просмотре на телефоне input'ы выезжают за форму, тк имеют 320px.
**grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(320px, 1fr))**
Или это можно сделать *только* через @media

https://jsfiddle.net/v6z86or5/

```
.container
   max-width: 1200px
   margin: auto
   padding: 0 30px

.contact-section
    background-color: #3b4c56

.contact-form
    max-width: 810px
    margin: 0 auto
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(320px, 1fr))
    background-color: #4f606a
    border: 1px solid #979ea2
    color: #a3b3bc
    padding: 50px

.single-input
    width: 320px
    height: 50px
    input
        width: 100%
        height: 100%
        background-color: #5e6d76
        border: 1px solid #979ea2
        padding: 0 20px
        color: #a3b3bc
        font-size: 18px
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вот так? https://jsfiddle.net/v6z86or5/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*долго не заморачиваясь -

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 680px){
    .container_for_input{
      display:flex;
      flex-flow:column nowrap;
      align-items:center;//по желанию
  }
    .class_input{
      width: 100%;
  }
  //если нужно по парно разместить input-ы
  .container_for_input{
      display:flex;
      flex-flow:row wrap; //если много полей
      justify-content:space-between;
  }
  
  .class_input{
    width: calc(50% - отступ/2 между input в px);
  }
  //остальные элементы по 100% ширины родителя
}
```

*